# Rendering issue: Camera keeps rendering the exact same scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I ran into a rendering problem: I set up a scene to render and it went well, then I moved the camera around, found a different angle but still in the same scene, when I tried to render it, Blender kept rendering the previous rendered scene (with the previous angles). How can fix this problem? I used Cycles. I also unchecked the sequencer option under post processing

Comment: Do you have a single camera in he scene?

Comment: if you press numpad 0, does it take you to the angle you are tring to render or to the angle it keeps rendering?

Comment: Does your camera have a keyframe set on it?  If so, it will "snap back" to the keyframed location.

Answer (score 2):

If your camera has a keyframe, that will override any future changes to your camera, unless you either set a new keyframe, or delete them. To check this, mouse over the timeline and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>left-arrow</kbd>. Then select your camera and move it to where you want it. Go back to the timeline and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>right-arrow</kbd>. If the camera moves back on its own, then you've put a keyframe on the camera.

If there's a keyframe, the select the camera and in the timeline you should see a yellow line. This is the frame where you keyframe was set. If you don't have any animation at all, then you can just delete **all keyframes**. To do that, open the Graph Editor, press <kbd>home</kbd>, select everything in that panel and delete it. If you *do* have animation that you want to keep, then you probably know how to find the keyframes for the camera and delete or modify them.

I hope that helps!